# Date from N days ago

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there less verbose way to get `date` N days ago?

```
select ('today'::date -'20 days'::interval)::date;
    date
------------
 2018-07-10
```

Comment: you can replace `'today'::date` with `now()`?.. also `select now()::date -20`should do, or `select current_date -20`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html has example (the very first `date` + `integer`, so you can omit `interval` and `date` casts:

```
db=# select current_date -20;
  ?column?
------------
 2018-07-10
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the "correct" way in Postgres is:

```
select current_date - interval '20 day'
```

Although you can use `- 20` as a shorthand for `- interval '20 day'`, I strongly recommend that you use the full `interval` form for clarity.

Comment: `select pg_typeof(current_date - interval '20 day');` => `timestamp without time zone`